# Bitlocker with TPM but without USB key?

Tags: windows-10, security, bitlocker, tpm, security-policy

I have Windows 10 x64 version 1903 build 18362.418. Recently I have added a TPM  module (specification version is 2.0) to my machine and as far as I can tell it is working properly: its Status in tpm.msc is "The TPM is ready for use." When I run Get-Tpm in Powershell, it also says "TpmPresent:True" and "TpmReady: True."

As for settings, for the policy

> Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative
>   Templates > Windows Components > Bitlocker Drive Encryption >
>   Operating System Drives > Require additional authentication at startup

if I set the top left corner to "Disabled" or "Not Configured," I get an error if I attempt to turn on Bitlocker for my OS drive:

> The startup options on this PC are configured incorrectly. Contact your
>   system administrator for more information.

If I have it to as below 
[image]

then Bitlocker asks me for a USB key on the very first step.

> **Question**: Is it possible to do Bitlocker with TPM but **without** the USB key?

I rather only use only the PIN or some password first then the PIN. I don't mind saving my recovery key to my MS account.

Thank you!

**Edit**: I previously enabled Bitlocker for this same drive. This was done **before** I had the TPM module and I did it by enabling "Allow Bitlocker without a compatible TPM (requires a password or a startup key on a USB flash drive). After adding the TPM, I have turned off Bitlocker beccause I thought I had to do it again now that I had the TPM but I ran into the problem described above. Also, now, when I run `managa-bde -status`, here is what I get:
[image: managa-bde -status]

---

Comment: _What_ error are you getting? Is the TPM for spec version 1.2 or 2.0? Is it activated in the computer's firmware settings? Is it recognized by `Get-Tpm` in PowerShell? Was it automatically initialized by Windows (tpm.msc)?

Comment: @grawity If I set the policy to "Disabled" or "Not configured" I get the error that says  "The startup options on this PC are configured incorrectly. Contact your system administrator for more information." TPM is version 2.0 and its Status in tpm.msc is "The TPM is ready for use." When I run Get-Tpm in Powershell, it also says "TpmPresent: True" and "TpmReady: True."

Comment: If your key was stored in the TPM you wouldn't be required to provide the key that exists on the USB device.  *Sounds like your key has not been stored on the TPM you installed.*

Comment: @Ramhound My TPM is literally only installed today so I havent done anything to it. How do I do what you are suggesting?

Comment: @yurnero - If the TPM is operational, then disabling BitLocker protection entirely, and enabling it again should present you the option to use the TPM instead of the current protection method.  I believe the command would be `manage-bde -tpm -turnon` but without knowing what the current status `manage -bde -status` that is difficult to determine

Comment: @Ramhound I added the output when I ran managa-bde -status.

Comment: @Ramhound I went ahead and did the encryption. And now sure enough, I need to insert the USB key every time the computer restarts. I know it's good for security but my work place is *that* unsafe so I'm willing to trade off some security for the convenience of just using a password or a password then a PIN.

Comment: @yurnero - Now that its actually encrypted.  You have to turn on the TPM, *manage-bde -tpm -turnon*, after you that there is a command to disable the password protector. However, no sense in submitting an answer, of your TPM isn’t functioning

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.x and Windows 10 require GPT partition style when using TPM 2.0. The BIOS setting for boot mode should be set to "Legacy Support Disable and Secure Boot Enable" (recommended) or "Legacy Support Disable and Secure Boot Disable".

Windows 7-64, Windows 8.x, and Windows 10 will work with MBR or GPT partition style when using TPM 1.2.

https://support.hp.com/hr-en/document/c05192291